# Long to wide creating new columns and populating values from previous column

Tags: r, sorting, data-cleaning, data-wrangling, wide-format-data

The answer to my question might be available and I am just no phrasing it correctly.

I have something similar to this:

| ID | Fruit | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1.12.22 |
| 1 | Orange | 3.10.20 |
| 2 | Blueberry | 12.8.06 |
| 3 | Apple | 15.9.08 |
| 3 | Apple | 12.2.02 |
| 3 | Tomato | 3.7.22 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |

I am using Rstudios and would like to change the above to a wide format and also automatically create new columns and populate values with the dates in ascending order. The maximum column number will depend on the ID with the most fruit.

I would like it to look like this:

| ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.10.20 | 1.12.23 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 12.8.06 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 3 | 12.2.02 | 15.9.08 | 3.7.22 | ... |
| . | . | . | . | ... |

As you have noticed I do not actually need the names of the fruit for the output, just the dates. I not know what the max n is of Fruitn as the data set is huge.

I hope the above makes sense.

I haven't been able to find the solution online, but that is probably because I am not explaining it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>%
   mutate(name = rank(dmy(Date)), .by = ID) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, values_from = Date,
               names_prefix = 'Fruit', names_sort = TRUE,  values_fill = '0')

# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID Fruit1  Fruit2  Fruit3
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> 
1     1 3.10.20 1.12.22 0     
2     2 12.8.06 0       0     
3     3 12.2.02 15.9.08 3.7.22
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It comes with an error. Error in 'mutate()': !Problem while computing 'name = rank(dmy(date))'. Caused by error in 'dmy()': !could not find function "dmy".

Comment: @Milskad that means you have an older version of tidyverse. `dmy` is in the lubridate package. Load that also and run the code

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. One error has led to another. Now I get the error "can't convert 'fill' <character> to <list>". Have tried to Google a solution, but can't seem to find one. My date column were characters and I changed them to date class eith ymd(), but still get the same error. Any suggestions?